# Using foreach loop to create links from an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, navbar

Please help me create links using a php foreach loop that iterates over an array which contains the names of navbar links for a webpage.

Currently my loop creates links but when you click on them an error 404 page and displays in the url (for example when clicking on "blog"):

```
...homebrew-actual/blog.php>Blog <a></li><li><a href="
```

I would like the url to go to:

```
... homebrew-actual/blog.php
```

without the html tags.

Here is my current PHP loop:

```
      <nav>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $navOptions = array('index', 'showcase','about','blog','contact','forums');

                    foreach($navOptions AS $navOption) {
                        if ($navOption == $currentPage) {
                            print '<li>' . '<a href="/homebrew-actual/' . $navOption . '.php'. 'class="current">' . ucfirst($navOption) . '</a></li>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<li>' . '<a href="/homebrew-actual/' . $navOption . '.php>' . ucfirst($navOption) . '</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>              
                <li class="special"><a href="shop.php" title="buy">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
```

Please help me identify a solution to create a links for a navbar using an array with the link names and use a for loop to link to those pages.

Thank you for checking out this question.

Comment: You're missing a closing quotation mark at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `"`:

```
 print '<li>' . '<a href="/homebrew-actual/' . $navOption . '.php'. 'class="current">' . ucfirst($navOption) . '</a></li>';
                         ^--start href                           ^---end of href, missing "
```

Since you never close the href string, you end up with broken HTML.